# Disable lambda concurrency for the same event

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a lambda that processes files by s3 event. Is it possible to prevent the execution of lambda for the same event? For example, I uploaded a file to s3 and It triggered lambda. While the lambda is working, I upload the same file again and don't want the lambda to execute parallel. The first lambda should be done and after that, the second one should be started. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, but you can always maintain a DDB table and check for record existence before further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as per Lamda functions, it works asynchronously, independently, and in isolation. As it meant to do a specific task in a serverless manner. You can't hold another execution of the lambda function.

if you implemented the trigger point as any files upload, it will trigger the lambda function.

However, what is a process and what is currently processing by the lambda function, you can use a database or file system to keep track of processed files and if you got the same files again in Lamda, return without processing the file or maybe existing result if you are storing.